# Cross compiling problems

Tags: c++, linux, arm, cross-platform

I have installed the cross compile tools in the ubuntu 16.04.And when I type `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -v`in the command line.The command line shows that the cross compiler can work as follows:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/nju/ti-processor-linux-sdk/linux-devkit/sysroots/x86_64-arago-linux/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/6.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: /home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/snapshots/gcc-linaro-6.2-2016.11/configure SHELL=/bin/bash --with-mpc=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-mpfr=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libmudflap --with-cloog=no --with-ppl=no --with-isl=no --disable-nls --enable-c99 --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --with-tune=cortex-a9 --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --enable-multiarch --with-build-sysroot=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/_build/sysroots/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-lto --enable-linker-build-id --enable-long-long --enable-shared --with-sysroot=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-checking=release --disable-bootstrap --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release/label/docker-trusty-amd64-tcwg-build/target/arm-linux-gnueabihf/_build/builds/destdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20161016 (Linaro GCC 6.2-2016.11)
```

But when I execute `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf`,the system cannot detect the arm-linux-gnueabihf tools.

```
configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gpp... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-aCC... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-CC... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-cxx... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-cc++... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-cl.exe... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-FCC... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-KCC... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-RCC... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-xlC_r... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-xlC... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for pthread_rwlock_init in -lpthread... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/ioctl.h usability... yes
checking sys/ioctl.h presence... yes
checking for sys/ioctl.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking gtk/gtk.h usability... no
checking gtk/gtk.h presence... no
checking for gtk/gtk.h... no
checking pthread.h usability... yes
checking pthread.h presence... yes
checking for pthread.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

WHich reason could cause this problem? How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you exported your toolchain path? You need to do that. In order to work.

How to know you exported or not?

type `echo $PATH` in your terminal it will show the path.

---

Solution to your problem: export your toolchain path.

Below is example toolchain path. You need to give the right path of your toolchain.

**Example:**

```
export PATH=/opt/your_toolchains/path/arm-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks very much.I typed `echo $PATH` in the command line,and the command returned the toolchain path where arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ were installed.But when configuring the project,the command line still prompt me that there is no arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.Is there any reason else that may cause the problem?

Comment: arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ is located at the bin folder of your toolchain. if you ls the bin folder it will list all the utility like `ld`, `gcc`, `g++`, `ar`, `as`, etc. You need to install this package in your host `sudo apt install g++`

Answer (score 1):

Well, **arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc** seems to be not part of the list printed by the configure script, does it? But I see a check for **arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++**. Is that one installed too?

Comment: Thanks for advicing.The arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ is installed too.The arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ and arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc are from the same toolchain.